# i want to work on different branches in git in my local repository which have different branches from origin set as upstream

Tags: git, github, git-bash

I am learning to use GitHub.
I want to work on different branches in git in my local repository which has different branches from origin set as upstream.

Do I have to create different folders for the branches in local or my computer to keep track of them or can I view codes of different branches using just one local repository and how?

Comment: You can always switch between branches via `git checkout`, is that what you're looking for?

Comment: You either checkout to move from branch to branch one at a time (and un-committed code will follow) or you need to clone the repository into additional folders to have them available simultaneously.

Comment: @crashmstr - you don't need to re-clone, you can use worktree instead

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are several ways

## `git checkout`

Using `git checkout <branch>` you "change" the content of your folder to reflect the files in the desired branch. Your "root" folder can contain content from a single branch every time

## `git worktree`

[image]

```
# Add "another" directory for a different branch
git worktree add <second path>/<branch name>
```

This will create **another folder** on your computer which allows you to work on different branches simultaneously.

```
### Creating new worktree

# create new branch inside the worktree folder 
git worktree -b <branch name> <path>

### Removing worktree

# Tell git to remove the workdir copy
git worktree delete ...
```

#### Listing worktree

[image]

[image]